# Generating Random text on Collision AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I would like to generate some random words when an object hits another one.

I've tried it but only one word comes up and never changes again.

Also would it be better if I make a new class for the random texts or is including it in the Main class good enough? Thanks!

Here's my current code:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;



public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var cell:Cell;
    public var group:Array;
    public var gameTimer:Timer;
    public var score:int = 0;
    var array:Array = new Array ("Apples",
                                 "Bananas",
                                 "Grapes",
                                 "Oranges",
                                 "Pineapples"); //create an array of possible strings
    var randomIndex:int =  Math.random () * array.length;
    //public var randomTxt:String;





    public function Main() {

        group = new Array();


        gameTimer = new Timer (25);
        gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,moveCell);
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    private function createCell(_x:Number = 0, _y:Number = 0):void {
        var cell:Cell = new Cell(_x, _y);
        group.push(cell);
        addChild(cell);
    }


     function moveCell (timerEvent:TimerEvent):void {

         if (Math.random() < 0.01) {
             var randomX:Number = Math.random()*800;
             var randomY:Number =  Math.random()*600;
             createCell(randomX, randomY);
         }


         for (var i:int = 0; i < group.length; i++)
         {
             var cell:Cell = Cell(group[i]);
             if (cell.hitTestObject(island))
             {
                 cell.parent.removeChild(cell);
                 group.splice(i,1);
                 score++;
                 txtWordDisplay.text = "Killed by" + array [randomIndex];


             }




         }

    scoreOutPut.text = score.toString();



    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the same word because you only set the `randomIndex` once at the beginning of your program.

A simple fix would be to update that value when the collision happens:

```
if (cell.hitTestObject(island))
{
    ...
    randomIndex =  Math.floor(Math.random () * array.length);
    txtWordDisplay.text = "Killed by" + array [randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Cadin!